# How to Break the For Loop and Continue Only When User Request it , in Php?

Tags: php, for-loop

Consider An API Result ,  Gives 10 Products Per Page.

Eg. http://api.example.com/key=XXX&type=1&cat=abc
Gives 10 Results 0 to 9

Eg. http://api.example.com/key=XXX&type=1&cat=abc&page=2
Gives Another 10 Results 0 to 9

I made a loop

```
$cnt = count($results) // 10
$page = 1;
$text = $_REQUEST['more'];

// I Want to break the loop to show 3 products only to user When the user clicks on the load more , then i have to show another 3 products..like this continues. 
for($i=0; $i<$cnt; $i++)
{
   if($i == 3) break;
   /*
    * My Stuffs.
   */
   if($text == 'more')
   {
      // i have to show 3 to 6 , Then 6 to 9 , Then page 2 , 0 to 2
   }

}
```

How to perform this type of breaking the loop an continue?

Comment: You have to use ajax.  Just search on this site for it.

Comment: Using ajax is not problem , How to  Perform the looping action is my doubt.

Comment: Sorry, the website api.example.com cannot be found.

Comment: Are the results coming from mysql?  And the HTML has a More button, when there are more results available, and when clicked the script is called again? Correct?  I have a good example, but need to know if I should strip the mysql.

Comment: @Misunderstood , The results are not coming from mysql , The results are coming from the 3rd party api as json

Comment: Umm... @Raaga if you are getting the results from 3rd party API, why are you using PHP? You are making the request with CURL at backend? Judging by `$results` var at the beginning of your code it is actually CURL or `file_get_contents` over HTTP URL.

Comment: There is no such interaction between a script and the user. The user makes a request, the script runs to its completion and returns a content, and the user/script interaction is limited to that. If you want more content to be generated as user request, you need a second script, that will generate only HTML for the new content, and this script will respond to a JavaScript request that will fetch and put the newly generated content in the place it belongs in the page. This method of interactive content is popularly known as AJAX.

Comment: check my answer. Is that what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE

My original hypothesis was the there could be a very large number of elements returned in the JSON.

If the number is relatively small I have a different approach

Generate the HTML with all the json elements and hide the "more" pages.

```
$json = file_get_contents('json.jsn',true);
$ndx = 0;
$id = 0;
$limit = 10;
echo '<div id="p0">';  
foreach($json as $value){
  echo "<p>$value</p>
  $ndx++;
  if($ndx == limit){
    $ndx = 0;
    $id++;
    echo "<button onclick=\"more($id)\">More</button></div>\n<div id=\"p$id\" class=\"hide\">
  }
}

echo <<<EOT
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
function more(id){
  document.getElementById('p' + id).style.display='none';
  id++;
  document.getElementById('p' + id).style.display='block';
}
//]]>
</script></div></body></html>
EOT;
```

**end of update**

---

This is tricky, but I like a challenge.

Rather than `&page=2` use `&ptr=$pointer` where `$pointer` is the value of the last or next record in the json object / array that was transmitted.

But the bigger issue is whether to store the json results temporarily or repeat the same request and start at the pointer location?

I'm going to go with store the results locally even though it will require a clean up job.

And I want to go with a POST rather than GET.

**I am still on the case, but I'd like to know if you think I should continue.**

```
if(intval($_GET['ptr'] == 0){
  $json = file_get_contents('json.jsn',true);
  $cnt = count($json);
  if ($cnt < 11){
    // output results, no next or previous buttons
  }
  else{
    // output results, include a next button:
        echo <<<EOT
<form action="this.php" ><div>
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="$user" />
<input type="hidden" name="ptr" value="10" />
<button>Next</button>
</div></form>
EOT;
    $fp = fopen('/home/user/public_html/json/' . "$user.ser",'w');
    fwrite($fp,serialize($json));
    fclose($fp);
  }
}
else{
  $json = unserialize(file_get_contents('/home/user/public_html/json/' . "$user.ser"));
  $cnt = count($json);
  $last = $ptr + 11;
  if($last > $cnt){
    $last = $cnt;  //no next button
  }else{
    // output results, include a next and previous buttons:
         echo <<<EOT
<form action="this.php" ><div>
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="$user" />
<input type="hidden" name="ptr" value="$last" />
<input type="hidden" name="direction" value="2" />
<button>Previous</button>
</div></form>
<form action="this.php" ><div>
<input type="hidden" name="user" value="$user" />
<input type="hidden" name="ptr" value="$last" />
<input type="hidden" name="direction" value="1" />
<button>Next</button>
</div></form>

  }  
  for($i=$ptr;$i<$last;$i++){
    // output records.
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at what I have done so far.  If you think I am on the right track, I will continue.  If you have questions, which I would expect you do, fire away.

Comment: I really hope that you're mixing HTML and PHP like that only for simplicity and not as your usual programming style...

Comment: This is my usual programming style.  My style is not typical, my style is usually misunderstood.  The question is, do you understand what I am doing and do you think I may be on the correct path?  It appears you would rather it be done in JavaScript more than in PHP.

Comment: There is absolutely no need to make such complicated auto-generated HTML forms in backend. OP's problem has already been solved long ago, with `offset` and `limit` parameters on API endpoints. Such a mixture of presentation layer and data layer is just horrible, it'll lead to problems with maintenance. At the very least, you are losing validation and highlighting of HTML code which your IDE provides to you, if you heredoc it like that.

Comment: @hijarian I must have missed the check mark from the OP next to your solution.  You may be correct.  I am going to wait for feedback from the OP, if that is okay with you.  We may not agree with what is complicated.

Comment: You are just trying to make the static HTML page with form button, which, after being submitted, return next three products and another auto-generated form. This is nice HTML-only solution and as it there's nothing wrong with it (apart from the implementation which mixes presentation and data layers), but in this case it's overly complicated, because it's 2015 and OP is surely trying to make some partially rich UI with Javascript. He needs a simple API endpoint at backend and complex UI logic at frontend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/76747/discussion-between-misunderstood-and-hijarian).

Answer (score 0):

I have rewritten my answer.

Your approach with `$_POST ['more']` is very hard to implement. Button "More" should send request with page number instead. `$_POST ['page']=:page_number`. How you will change the page number in button depends on implementation of your UI, be it rich JS UI or plain HTML pages updating by browser navigation.

If you make "More" button pass the page number, your  problem will become a problem of getting 3-element pages from 10-element ones, which is easily solvable.

Comment: This looks as if you want to use AJAX to get next set of products.  What is your estimated maximum number of products that could be requested?

Comment: Of course I want to use AJAX to get next set of products. OP is asking "When user clicks 'load more' I have to show another 3 products". His example URLs start with "api", which means, he has JSON API endpoints or I don't quite understand what's he trying to do here at all. So, the solution is as I described it above.

Comment: @Misunderstood Max number of products that could be requested depends on your server hardware. You should put sane hardcoded limits in your code anyway. In OP's case limit will always be 3, it can be even hardcoded at backend and not made as a GET request parameter.

Comment: I would think the max number of products depends on the max number of products that the request could produce.  I'm not sure about three or ten as the questions says "Gives 10 Products Per Page", then the sample code posted show something regarding three.  idk.

Comment: @Misunderstood There's the default number of products which we return when there's no `limit` parameter passed to us and there's the hardcoded limit on the number of products to return to not fill our hardware RAM and saturate the network channel with data. In OP's code there's indication that he wants to show to user products only in batches of 3. This is business requirement. Everything else is safety measures and UX improvements by us.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 
$results =  array('abc', 'def', 'ghi', 'jkl', 'nmo', 'pqr', 'stu', 'vwx', 'yz1', '234', '567', '890', 'zaq' );
$cnt = count($results); // 12
$page = 1;
$text = $_REQUEST['more']; //'more';

// I Want to break the loop to show 3 products only to user When the user clicks on the load more , 
//then i have to show another 3 products..like this continues. 

$i = 0;

//page 1
for($i; $i < 4; $i++){

    //whatever you want to do
}

if($text == 'more'){

    while($cnt > $i){

        if($page == 1){

            for($j=4; $j<10 && $j < $cnt; $j++){

                for($k = $j; $k < $j+3; $k++){
                    //next three records
                }

                $j = $k-1;

            }
            $page++;
        }else{

            //new page
            $val = $page*10;
            for($j=($page-1)*10; $j< $val && $j < $cnt; $j++){

                for($k = $j; $k < $j+3; $k++){
                    //next three records
                }

                $j = $k-1;
            }
            $page++;
        }

        $i = $j;
    }

}

?>
```